# Margin references in tufte-handout with pandoc

Tags: biblatex, tufte, pandoc, markdown

I'm trying to convert a Markdown file to PDF using pandoc and a `tufte-handout` template. I would like to have references in the margin, instead of in the end of the document, is this even possible in a direct MD->PDF conversion?

Comment: You'll want to make a MWE for this: a simple Pandoc document with one reference, plus your tufte-handout template (possibly minimized to avoid extra package loading or other unlreated macros).

Comment: As far as I know there are multiple ways to generate citations in Pandoc. Can you make sure that you are actually using LaTeX packages to do that (i.e. not CLS files)? If you use a LaTeX solution make sure to tag your question accordingly, do you really use `biblatex`? It will really be easier to diagnose your problem if we get to see what you are trying to do (code as well as compilation sequence).

Answer (score 2):

When using the `tufte-handout` class, any footnotes automatically go into the margin. If you're using `pandoc-citeproc` for references, download a notes style such as Chicago Full Note from the [Zotero styles repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles), place it in `~/.csl/`, and then you'll be able to use it from anywhere when creating a PDF. An example file:

```
---
documentclass: tufte-handout
csl: chicago-fullnote-bibliography.csl
---

test^[Footnote.]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the easies way is to use rmarkdown, but the effect is the same in pure pandoc. Just need to adapt the template as previous comment suggested. With rmarkdown, this is how it goes down:

In latest rmarkdown you only need to use a csl that changes references into footnotes and add both tufte-handout and disablebibliography in your yaml header:

```
---
bibliography: library.bib
csl: chicago-fullnote-bibliography.csl
suppress-bibliography: yes
output: 
    bookdown::tufte_book2:
        toc: yes
        highlight: tango
---
```